# form not saving to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, datepicker

I am trying to save the data which is inserted into a form , When I press save & proceed it goes to the 'new' again and i have tried to change the false action in the controller and redirect it to any page of the application but it is not respond to the false action at all , and the url in the browser changes to :

```
0.0.0.0:3000/students/15/student_previous_data/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&student_previous_data[student_id]=15&student_previous_data[institution]=institution&student_previous_data[course]=course&student_previous_data[year]=2010&student_previous_data[total_mark]=60&commit=Save+%26+Proceed
```

For the year attribute I am using bootstrap-datepicker , and I use this JQuery Code

```
jQuery ->
  $(".year").datepicker( { format: "yyyy", viewMode: "years", minViewMode: "years", autoclose: true });
```

and that is the create action in my controller

```
  def create
    @student_previous_data = StudentPreviousData.new(params[:student_previous_data])
    if @student_previous_data.save
      flash[:success] = 'Record Saved Successfully.'
      redirect_to '/user/dashboard'
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'An error occurred please try again!'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

student_previous_data/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Admission</h1>
<h4>Step 3 - Previous details</h4>

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span5 offset1 hero-unit">
    <%= bootstrap_form_for(@student_previous_data, :url => new_student_student_previous_datum_path(@student),
                           html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }, method: :get) do |f| %>
        <% if @student_previous_data.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <div class="alert alert-error">
                The form contains <%= pluralize(@student_previous_data.errors.count, 'error') %>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <% @student_previous_data.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li>* <%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
        <% end %>


            <fieldset>
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.hidden_field :student_id, value: @student.id %>

              </div>

              <h4>Previous Educational Details</h4>
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.text_field :institution, label: 'Institution Name'%>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.text_field :course, label: 'Course'%>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.text_field :year , class: 'year', label: 'Year' %>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.text_field :total_mark, label: 'Total Mark'%>
              </div>
              <div class="actions"><%= f.submit 'Save & Proceed', class: 'btn btn-mini btn-primary' %></div>
            </fieldset>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

after running `Rake routes` command:

```
        student_previous_data_index GET    /student_previous_data/index(.:format)                         student_previous_data#index
         student_previous_data_show GET    /student_previous_data/show(.:format)                          student_previous_data#show
          student_previous_data_new GET    /student_previous_data/new(.:format)                           student_previous_data#new
         student_previous_data_edit GET    /student_previous_data/edit(.:format)                          student_previous_data#edit
                    guardians_index GET    /guardians/index(.:format)                                     guardians#index
                     guardians_show GET    /guardians/show(.:format)                                      guardians#show
                     guardians_edit GET    /guardians/edit(.:format)                                      guardians#edit
                     students_index GET    /students/index(.:format)                                      students#index
                      students_show GET    /students/show(.:format)                                       students#show
                      students_edit GET    /students/edit(.:format)                                       students#edit
                   article_comments GET    /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)                       comments#index
                                    POST   /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)                       comments#create
                new_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/new(.:format)                   comments#new
               edit_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)              comments#edit
                    article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)                   comments#show
                                    PUT    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)                   comments#update
                                    DELETE /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)                   comments#destroy
                           articles GET    /articles(.:format)                                            articles#index
                                    POST   /articles(.:format)                                            articles#create
                        new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                                        articles#new
                       edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                                   articles#edit
                            article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                                        articles#show
                                    PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                                        articles#update
                                    DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                                        articles#destroy
                              users GET    /users(.:format)                                               users#index
                                    POST   /users(.:format)                                               users#create
                           new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                           users#new
                          edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                                      users#edit
                               user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                           users#show
                                    PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                           users#update
                                    DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                           users#destroy
      student_student_previous_data GET    /students/:student_id/student_previous_data(.:format)          student_previous_data#index
                                    POST   /students/:student_id/student_previous_data(.:format)          student_previous_data#create
 new_student_student_previous_datum GET    /students/:student_id/student_previous_data/new(.:format)      student_previous_data#new
edit_student_student_previous_datum GET    /students/:student_id/student_previous_data/:id/edit(.:format) student_previous_data#edit
     student_student_previous_datum GET    /students/:student_id/student_previous_data/:id(.:format)      student_previous_data#show
                                    PUT    /students/:student_id/student_previous_data/:id(.:format)      student_previous_data#update
                                    DELETE /students/:student_id/student_previous_data/:id(.:format)      student_previous_data#destroy
                  student_guardians GET    /students/:student_id/guardians(.:format)                      guardians#index
                                    POST   /students/:student_id/guardians(.:format)                      guardians#create
               new_student_guardian GET    /students/:student_id/guardians/new(.:format)                  guardians#new
              edit_student_guardian GET    /students/:student_id/guardians/:id/edit(.:format)             guardians#edit
                   student_guardian GET    /students/:student_id/guardians/:id(.:format)                  guardians#show
                                    PUT    /students/:student_id/guardians/:id(.:format)                  guardians#update
                                    DELETE /students/:student_id/guardians/:id(.:format)                  guardians#destroy
                           students GET    /students(.:format)                                            students#index
                                    POST   /students(.:format)                                            students#create
                        new_student GET    /students/new(.:format)                                        students#new
                       edit_student GET    /students/:id/edit(.:format)                                   students#edit
                            student GET    /students/:id(.:format)                                        students#show
                                    PUT    /students/:id(.:format)                                        students#update
                                    DELETE /students/:id(.:format)                                        students#destroy
                           sessions GET    /sessions(.:format)                                            sessions#index
                                    POST   /sessions(.:format)                                            sessions#create
                        new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                                        sessions#new
                       edit_session GET    /sessions/:id/edit(.:format)                                   sessions#edit
                            session GET    /sessions/:id(.:format)                                        sessions#show
                                    PUT    /sessions/:id(.:format)                                        sessions#update
                                    DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)                                        sessions#destroy
                     user_dashboard GET    /user/dashboard(.:format)                                      static_pages#home
                 student_admission1 GET    /student/admission1(.:format)                                  students#new
                 student_admission2 GET    /student/admission2(.:format)                                  guardians#new
                               root        /                                                              sessions#new
```

How do i make the form go to the true to save in the database ?

Comment: What does your view code look like for the save/proceed logic?

Comment: question updated , i added the new.html.erb

Comment: your url is wrong. run rake routes and find the right route

Comment: rake routes added to the question , what should i do ??

Comment: Start with a Rails Guides. Looks like you have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: @MostafaHussein, dude i think you should spend some time learning rails, otherwise you will get stuck for hours with very simple problem like you are facing now.

Comment: i finished the michael hartl tutorial and i made an application before , but now the recent application can be considered as advanced for me , and i am trying to learn by doing it and face problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem in the name itself , the controller should accept the name as `singular` but the form accepts the name as `plural` , i have created a new `controller` and `model` with the name `'previous_detail'` in the controller it should be >> `redirect_to new_student_previous_detail_path(@student)` and in the form should be `student_previous_details_path(@student)`

Answer (score 1):

Your form url is not correct. Your url should look like following:

```
:url => student_student_previous_data_path(@student)
```

Your current url

```
:url => new_student_student_previous_datum_path(@student)
```

always will redirect you directly to your new action. You will never pass the create action.

Comment: i have tried this before and tried now again to make sure ,, its not working , because it raises an error before redirecting to the new form , this is my previous error and it will happen again if i used your solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353929/cant-reach-to-the-next-form-ror-3

Comment: You also have `method: :get`. You need to POST.

Comment: dude , i have tried but it raises , Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"student_previous_data", :student_id=>#<Student id: 22, admission_no: "995", class_roll_no: nil, admission_date: nil, first_name: "aaa", middle_name: "bbb", last_name: "ccc"...

Answer (score 1):

You're using `GET` method, use `POST` method.

And use `student_student_previous_data_path(@student)` in url

Comment: Not working it raises Routing Error No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"student_previous_data", :student_id=>#<Student id: 22, admission_no: "995", class_roll_no: nil, admission_date: nil, first_name: "aaa", middle_name: "bbb", last_name: "ccc"..

Comment: It shouldn't access show action for the POST method. Can you please paste your `routes.rb` file?

Answer (score 1):

change your form_for to

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@student_previous_data, :url => student_student_previous_data_path(@student),
                       html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }, method: :post) do |f| %>
```

from

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@student_previous_data, :url => new_student_student_previous_datum_path(@student),
                       html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }, method: :get) do |f| %>
```

and it will work.